# How can I split data to columns and values in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, string

I have a data like this

```
id:123;qty:1,00;price:1,25;sprice:2,00;id:125;qty:2,00;price:2,25;sprice:3,00;
```

I want to get result like this
[image]

And I also need column names `id,qty,price,sprice` because I will create an insert query.

```
`DECLARE @query
SET @query='INSERT INTO xtable ('+@columns+')
SELECT '+@columns+' from ytable'
EXEC (@query)`
```

Is there any way to do it without loop (while) ?

Comment: *Attempt* to convert it to JSON, "pray" it's valid JSON and then consume that? If it's going to end up *not* being valid JSON, then using a different language and having that send it to SQL Server would likely be your best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, one method would be to *attempt* to transform the string you have into something that SQL server *can* parse. I'm going to go for JSON here.

As, however, many of your numerical values use commas, rather than periods, for the decimal separator then you'll need to consume the values as a string value first and then convert that to a numerical data type afterwards. I use `TRY_PARSE` with a culture to achieve this in the below solution.

To transform the data into valid JSON, based solely on the example we have, I trim the semicolons (`;`) from the string, replace the remaining semicolons with a quoted comma,(`","`), replace colons (`:`) with quoted colons (`":"`). I also *assume* `id` will always be the first element, so that I can start a new JSON object at that value, and then can wrap the entire string in braces (`{}`), and brackets (`[]`).

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = 'id:123;qty:1,00;price:1,25;sprice:2,00;id:125;qty:2,00;price:2,25;sprice:3,00;';

DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = '[{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(';' FROM @YourString),':','":"'),';','","') + '"}]';

SET @JSON = REPLACE(@JSON, ',"id"', '},{"id"');

PRINT @JSON

SELECT id,
       TRY_PARSE(qty as decimal(12,2) USING 'fr-fr') AS qty,
       TRY_PARSE(price as decimal(12,2) USING 'fr-fr') AS price,
       TRY_PARSE(sprice as decimal(12,2) USING 'fr-fr') AS sprice
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (id int,
           qty varchar(10),
           price varchar(10),
           sprice varchar(10));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zyak6dnL)

Comment: that is pretty good idea for choosing data, but i also need column names for example id,qty,price,sprice because I will make a query and use Exec

Comment: The query results *has* the columns `id`, `qty`, `price` and `sprice`, so I don't get what you mean.